# Count a random dice

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I am really confused with what I'm doing here I am not sure why it is not working for me.
I can print out random rolls for numbers 1-6 but now I am trying to do two other things:

1. Print out the average dice value of all the rolls
2. Which is the most frequent side of the dice

```
import random

def rollDie(number):
    rolls = [0] * 6
    for i in range(0, number):
        roll=int(random.randint(1,6))
        rolls[roll - 1] += 1
    return rolls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = rollDie(50)
    i = result
    print (result)
    print(i/6)
```

Comment: `random.randint()` returns an integer already, no need to call `int()` on that again.

Comment: And where are you struggling then? How to get the maximum value from `result` (the most frequent dice value thrown) or how to calculate the sum of all values thrown so you can calculate the average?

Comment: Or are you struggling with implementing the maths here? Is this a maths or a Python problem for you?

Comment: I am struggling with implementing the math figure out the process

Comment: Do you understand what `rollDie()` produces at all? What each of the values in the list mean?

Comment: The rollDie() should produce around 50 rolls. I would need help trying to add the rolls all together then getting the average

Comment: That's not what I am asking. `rollDie()` produces a list of integers. What do those integers stand for?

Comment: I'm sorry but now I'm confused haha. I think the rollDie() integers should stand for the numbers of dice so 1-6. am I correct?

Comment: There are always 6 integers in that list.. What happens when a 1 is thrown (so `random.randint(1,6)` returns `1` and thus `roll = 1`). Or a 2, or a 3, etc.?

Comment: That is correct of what should be happening

Comment: I'm trying to see if you understand what the numbers stand for. I understand the numbers just fine. Only when you understand what those numbers *mean* can you start to figure out how to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh okay sorry. Thought you were trying to help me with that. So the numbers are basically one Dice that would be rolled about 50 times. Now after the 50 times it prints out how many times 1,2,3,4,5,6 had rolled. Now I would need help figuring out the frequent of the results.

Comment: So can figure out which one was the *most* frequent? Not with code, just explaining how you'd go about that.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, It's a project for school now its extremely confused me with the professors wording.

Comment: @TheNewGuy if I gave you a list with elements `[3,7,12,30,4,4]`, could you tell me which one was the biggest?

Comment: @AdamSmith the number 30

Comment: Now how do you make your program pick the biggest element? (hint: the max value). How do you make your program calculate the average?

Answer (score 1):

The first question you pose needs a bit of clarification; what is it exactly that you are looking for in the "average" value thrown? To answer your second question, the function you gave us conducts a *number* amount of dice rolls, saving them to a list corresponding to each die number. All you have to do to see the most popular face rolled is print the list and look for the largest number. Alternatively, you can use the `array.index( max( array ) )` to find the index or 'die face' of the most rolled face.

```
import random

def rollDie(number):
    rolls = [0] * 6
    for i in range(0, number):
        roll=int(random.randint(1,6)) # try to avoid naming things like this
        rolls[roll - 1] += 1
    return rolls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = rollDie(50)
    i = result
    print (result)  # you can just look at the largest value in the array
    print(i/6)      # this is dividing a list by an integer....

    print result.index(max(result)) # This will print the index of the post rolled face
                                    # i.e if one was the most rolled it would print 0
```

To be more explicit what you should have is:

```
import random

def rollDie(number):
    rolls = [0] * 6
    for i in range(0, number):
        roll=int(random.randint(1,6))
        rolls[roll - 1] += 1
    return rolls

result = rollDie(50)
print (result)  
print result.index(max(result))
```

Comment: Due to the line `print(i/6)` that you had previously in there, which is why i commented in the code that it doesnt make sense. Remove that and it will work.

Comment: What does this line do : print result.index(max(result))

Comment: So the line `print result.index(max(result))` starts with a *print* function call. You should know that this simply tells python to print out whatever we have to the right of it. *result* is our output, a list of six numbers that tell us how many times each die face was rolled during our experiment. The *.index()* is called a *data item*. This is sort of like a function that has a special purpose specifically for arrays, such as our *result* array. index( max(result) ) asks python what the *index* of the maximum value is. An index is the placement of a value in the list, hence the die face.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

def rollDie(number): # cleaner version
    results = []
    for i in range(0, number):
        results.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    return results

def most_common(lst): # quick dirty lambda to calc the most occurring roll
    return max(((item, lst.count(item)) for item in set(lst)), key=lambda a: a[1])[0]

results = rollDie(50) # 50 rolls
total = 0 # creating total
for i in results:
    total += i # adding up all the dice rolls
print(total) # total
print(total / 50) # Average from the 50 dice rolled
print(round(total / 50)) # rounded Average
print(most_common(results)) # most occuring number
```